# Change data capture (CDC) SSIS not working

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, change-data-capture

I am trying to implement change data capture in SQL Server 2012. I enabled it at database and table level. when i try to update the table, CDC_CT captures the changes. However when i am using SSIS CDC components, it doesnt pick anything.

the version of SQL server is: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU10-GDR) (KB4057121) - 11.0.6615.2 (X64) Jan 9 2018 21:26:48 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Can someone please guide?

[image: CDC_Initial_Load]

[image: CDC_Mark_Changes]

[image: CDC_Data_Flow]

Comment: This is too broad to troubleshoot with the information supplied. We can't see your SSIS package, your CDC configurations, and would be guessing. This is also more DBA related, which is better suited for dba.stackexchange.com IMHO.

Comment: @scsimon : Thanks. I have Added the pictures to provide more information.

Comment: @scsimon : i asked this question there too.

Comment: Need more information on the error you are facing, But here are the basics step that i would suggest.1) cdc.dbo_<your table name>_CT table if it has captured the changes 2) can you able to run the intial load without any problem 3)check for the CDC_STATE value 4) Run the incremental load and check if the CDC_STATE table is marking the watermark correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with SP3 in sql server 2012. As soon as I installed SP4 this issue went away.